# Error when used consolidate node package

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify

I tried to used [consolidate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/consolidate) package with gulp to build the MEAN stack app. But I don't know why when I run `npm install`, then `gulp browserify`, it always threw a lot of exceptions like

```
Browserify Error { [Error: Cannot find module 'hogan.js' from '<my project path>\node_modules\consolidate\lib']
  stream:
   { _readableState:
      { highWaterMark: 16,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: [Object],
        pipesCount: 1,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null,
        resumeScheduled: false },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Object],
        error: [Object],
        data: [Function: ondata],
        _mutate: [Object] },
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      { highWaterMark: 16,
        objectMode: true,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [],
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: true,
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _options: { objectMode: true },
     _wrapOptions: { objectMode: true },
     _streams: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     length: 2,
     label: 'deps' } }
[16:01:17] Browserify Error { [Error: Cannot find module 'handlebars' from '<my project path>\node_modules\consolidate\lib']
  stream:
   { _readableState:
      { highWaterMark: 16,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: [Object],
        pipesCount: 1,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null,
        resumeScheduled: false },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Object],
        error: [Object],
        data: [Function: ondata],
        _mutate: [Object] },
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      { highWaterMark: 16,
        objectMode: true,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [],
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: true,
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _options: { objectMode: true },
     _wrapOptions: { objectMode: true },
     _streams: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     length: 2,
     label: 'deps' } }
[16:01:17] Browserify Error { [Error: Cannot find module 'underscore' from '<my project path>\node_modules\consolidate\lib']
```

I guess that something wrong in consolidate package, because it did not install package recursively. My consolidate version that I used is 0.12.1. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you installed the packages that are throwing errors?

Comment: @BenFortune Not actually, all packages installed successfully. It only threw errors when I run `gulp browserify`. I tried to `cd` into that module then run `npm install` manually, then I can overcome those errors. Don't know what's happen?

Answer (score 0):

Consolidate does not contain any template engine. You should install them on your level.

I guess you are using `hogan` templates, so you need to install it. Run this in your project root

```
npm install hogan.js --save
```